# Permission denial: Can't access the SurfaceFlinger

Tags: android

I get this error when running my app. I also included the permission for surfaceFlinger in manifest.xml

```
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"
```

but still it give the same error `" can't access the SurfaceFlinger"`  in LogCat.

Basically i want to run the Development setting code in Dev tools.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    try {
        Class partypes[] = new Class[1];
        partypes[0] = String.class;
        Method getService= ServiceManager.getMethod("getService", partypes );
        Object arglist[] = new Object[1];
        arglist[0] = "SurfaceFlinger";
        IBinder flinger= (IBinder)getService.invoke(smObject, arglist );

  //    IBinder flinger = ServiceManager.getService("SurfaceFlinger");
        if (flinger != null) {
            Parcel data = Parcel.obtain();
            data.writeInterfaceToken("android.ui.ISurfaceComposer");
            data.writeInt(isChecked ? 1 : 0);
            flinger.transact(mCode, data, null, 0);
            data.recycle();

            updateFlingerOptions();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    } 
**catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        String err=e.toString();
        Toast.makeText(DevelopmentSetting.this, err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }**

    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In catch SecurityException it gives the error java.lang.securityException but logcat it says  permission denied : can't access surfaceFlinger.

and the manifest.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nustian.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"   />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".DevelopmentSetting"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Somebody help me.

Comment: please post the full exception.

Answer (score 4):

Your app needs to be signed with the platform certificate to access this permission. Only system apps generally have this. More info here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/aN6D_vL9xxE

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, add this to your manifest file. UID media is able to use the surface flinger APIs, so sharing UID with it will allow your app to use it as well.

```
  coreApp="true"
  android:sharedUserId="android.uid.media"
```

Comment: Worked for me... where my app is a system app.

Comment: This approach does not work for me, ... I get an INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE installation error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add its relative permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
```

Comment: I added the relative permission but still it gives SecurityException error.

Comment: you should always include error stack too. otherwise no one can figure out what could be wrong...

Comment: paste your entire AndroidManifest.xml