# Trying to reboot programmatically rooted Android device

Tags: android, root

I'm trying to reboot programmatically my Galaxy S3.

Things that I've tried:

```
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("RebootActivity", "Could not reboot", ex);
    }

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot now"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {           
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("reboot now\n");
    } 
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do you guys have any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: If I try `/system/bin/su`, I get this exception: `java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/su, -c, reboot now] Working Directory: null Environment: null`

Comment: You have to type `"adb shell chmod 777 /dev/tty<>"` each time you restart the emulator
(of course replace /dev/tty<>" by your serial device)

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal, I'm not using an emulator. I'm using a Galaxy S3 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to do one normal string looking like 《su \n reboot; \n》 instead of an array.
Try to get the answer from the shell, that helps a lot for debugging.

What are the permissions of your su binary? If they would be wrong, you could try to 《chmod 7777 /system/xbin/su》 after 《mount -o remount,rw /system》

Here is some example code: (to run the string command, which is a \n and or ; separated list of linux shell commands)

```
StringBuffer commandOutput = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su\n");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/vendor/lib:/system/lib\n");
        out.writeBytes(command+"\n");
        out.flush();

        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int numRead;
        char[] buffer = new char[1000];
        while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            commandOutput.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        in.close();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch ...

    return commandOutput.toString();
```

Comment: How do I get the answer from the shell? Thanks!

Comment: This code returns this error: `W/System.err(26960): java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)`

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615412/android-write-failed-epipe-broken-pipe-error-on-write-file

Comment: It's strange, because this works on the emulator. Also, my galaxy S3 is a rooted device, so I don't know why I'm having this error.

Comment: Did you check the su file permissions? Do you have a superuser apk installed which allows or denies su access? What if you uninstall it? (the apk)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the `PowerManager` to make it reboot (this does not guarantee that it'll reboot - OS may cancel it):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT