# Android - how teamviewer native touch works

Tags: java, android, touch, teamviewer

I have already read about the android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS and the usage of Instrumentation class, but with it, your app needs system sign, and special installation form into system folder. 
I also have read about the adb possibilities to simulate touch, swipe etc.. events, but it is a very limited function which is basically not enought for me.

My question is, that what is the technical background of (for example) teamviewer, which is usable after a normal installation from android market with only a little permission requirement. I have no idea how TeamViewer's Samsung Quicksupport can simulate touch event's.

Because I can easily imagine that computer send command to the phone, and the phone make the touch event on a coordinate.

Anybody have any idea about it how teamviewer works on android and how could I write some similar functionality to force touch events considering the fact that their application can be installed via market with little permission?

Comment: Nobody have any idea about it?

Comment: @grunk: What you seek is not possible, outside of accessibility services or specific deals with specific device manufacturers. TeamViewer uses the latter approach.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's a similar question as in [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89597/how-remote-control-remote-desktop-on-android-works-e-g-teamviewer).

Although I find the need of "[Add-on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.addon.allview&hl=en)" besides the main app. 
This add-on written for almost every phone manufacture. can be find in [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5432474436276944851).
proof to this is "Remotely control Android devices (available for Samsung, HTC, LG, ZTE, and more)" written in [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile-apps/)

Permissions these add-on uses are:

- SurfaceFlinger
- capture secure video output
- capture video output
- press keys and control buttons
- read frame buffer

**But** using permissions like '' need to have a system app or [to be signed with the platform certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18918631/1454173) . Thus I can say this is why they made so many add-on (based on manufacturer {System certificate signer})

I can think of that they wrote an open source app and asked for manufacturers to sign it (Individually).